# How to minimize signin scripting attack

Tags: security, scripting

I'll jump right into the problem.
Let's say my website has sign-in capability and has a lots of users. 
I'm getting sign-in scripting attacks where the hacker has list of "username" and "password"(let's say he got this from elsewhere) and he's running it on my website to see if they're a valid information.
I have a monitoring tool/app to catch if same IP address is trying to attempt "x" amount of  logins within "y" amount of time and it successfully detects attacks which falls into those categories. However there are limitations to this as I'm unable to come up with all possible cases, I feel like it's impossible to stop them from this these types of attacks. 
I'm curious how other companies like Amazon or other giants handles these type of attacks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could present an account with a CAPTCHA once a certain number of failed login attempts occur, regardless of the IP address. It's annoying, so I would advise against it. If users use stupid passwords, it's not your responsibility to completely protect them from attacks like this.

Comment: There is not one correct solution to stop this problem. However you can try to slow down this behavior until it takes too long for the hacker to accomplish his goals and he gets fed up with it.

Comment: @ZippyV: If someone really wants to attack your site, they probably won't be using just one bot.

Answer (score 1):

They apply various techniques to determine if the login is done my a human or not - this is known as  [Turing test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test)

For example, many sites lock out users out if they try too many login attempts within a fixed time period. This means that if it is a bot, it's later login attempts will be ignored. A variation on this is to increase the lock out time as the number of login attempts increase.

A [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is used in sites like Ticketmaster.

Brute-force attacks such as this are unfortunately a fact of life.

Comment: I'm talking about many different "username"&"password" sets. So hacker would try each username once and move to next and so on.

Comment: Your IP monitoring is the best tools for this if there is only 1 login attempt per username.